# I could curl using IP but not using consul serviceName?

Tags: docker, consul, registrator

I am trying to teach myself consul. I created a dockerized consul and a REST service that just returns 'Hello World', invoking curl on the consul to get the information, nets me

```
$ curl $(docker-machine ip):8500/v1/catalog/service/hello-server | json_pp
[
   {
      "ServiceEnableTagOverride" : false,
      "CreateIndex" : 87,
      "ModifyIndex" : 87,
      "ServiceAddress" : "192.168.99.100",
      "Node" : "bootstrap-node",
      "Address" : "192.168.99.100",
      "ServiceTags" : [],
      "ServiceID" : "5a251b3a7821:hello-server:80",
      "TaggedAddresses" : {
         "wan" : "192.168.99.100",
         "lan" : "192.168.99.100"
      },
      "NodeMeta" : {},
      "ID" : "102b597f-0b4c-4702-985e-327a5a022cc7",
      "ServiceName" : "hello-server",
      "ServicePort" : 32775
   }
]
```

pinging the hello-server led me to believe that the endpoint is alive:

```
ping -qc 1 hello-server.service.consul
PING hello-server.service.consul (62.138.239.45): 56 data bytes

--- hello-server.service.consul ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 31.035/31.035/31.035/0.000 ms
```

However when I try to curl using the following, it will fail:

```
curl hello-server.service.consul:32775
```

Yet, using the following works:

```
curl 192.168.99.100:32775
Hello World
```

Do I need to specify some sort of DNS address when running docker-compose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Docker's embedded DNS is for container-to-container service discovery. If you want to connect from outside of a docker container to a published port, you'll need to setup DNS yourself to point a hostname to the docker host.